# SONiC requires Docker version 17.06.1 or later

Tags: docker, sonic

I'm trying to build a SONiC virtual switch image by following these instructions https://github.com/Azure/sonic-buildimage.
This issue I have is that when I run "make init", I get this error

```
Makefile.work:69: *** SONiC requires Docker version 17.06.1 or later.  Stop.
```

However, my docker version is 20.10.3

```
~/sonic-buildimage$ sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.3
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        48d30b5
 Built:             Fri Jan 29 14:33:13 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.3
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       46229ca
  Built:            Fri Jan 29 14:31:25 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
~/sonic-buildimage$
```

So what am I doing wrong? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your system to allow running the 'docker' command without 'sudo': Add current user to the docker group sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

Make sure to Log out and log back in. This will certainly solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be very helpful, but I was running into the same issue when i run make init. Thought the issue was with my local user not being in the docker group (had already added user, but still...) or that the docker service was not running (tried starting the service but that didn't help).
Just to be sure all docker services or required sockets were not put in an active when i installed moby-engine, i rebooted my PC and checked the status of my docker service (it was disabled). Tried running make init again and it was successful.
I had to *sssd* though as I had seen an error related to this when i installed docker. Possibly that the db cleaned up after the reboot helping make init run.